# How to load external razor component library's components with isolated CSS files using DynamicComponent

Tags: c#, blazor

I want to be able to load a RCL dll file, and render it's components dynamically:

**Index.razor**

```
<DynamicComponent Type="@componentType" />

@code {
    Type? componentType = Assembly.LoadFile(@"path_To_dll\ExternalRCL.dll")
        .GetType("ExternalRCL.ExternalComponent");
}
```

In `ExternalRCL.dll` file:

**ExternalComponent.razor**

```
<div class="my-component">
    This component is defined in the <strong>ExternalRCL</strong> library.
</div>
```

**ExternalComponent.razor.css**

```
.my-component {
    border: 2px dashed red;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em 0;
    background-image: url('background.png');
}
```

But the CSS isolation does not work currently. Anyone has an idea how to get the css working?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A common issue I see is when copying components to the class library the scoped css files are no longer copied to output on build. Double check properties of the css files and make sure they are copied to output on build.